# ReactDOM Hydrate Renders HTML as Text on Client Page

Tags: reactjs, react-dom-server

I am trying to do a simple test and I know I am missing something simple.

I have two applications, one hosted on node (localhost:3000) and another is hosted on another site (http://development.azure).  The section site is not running under node, its standard IIS.

In my node server application i have the following

```
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server"

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const name = 'Marvelous Peter'
    res.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>My Page</title></head><body>");
    res.write("<div id='content'>");
    res.write(renderToString(<Hello name={name} />));
    res.write("</div></body></html>");
    res.end();
});

app.listen(3000)
```

In my IIS application I am attempting to load the react component using xhr and then hydrate it.

```
const xhr = require("xhr");

        xhr({
            method: "GET",
            uri: "http://localhost:3000",

        }, (err, resp, body) => {
            // check resp.statusCode
            ReactDOM.hydrate(body, document.getElementById("test"),  () => {

            });
        });
```

I am seeing the output on my page, however, it is not HTML encoded.  I renders as text

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>My Page</title></head><body><div id='content'><div data-reactroot=""><h1>Hello, <!-- -->Marvelous Peter<!-- -->!</h1></div></div></body></html>
```

I tried returning only the renderToString value and not HTML and still get the same thing, specifically since i have  tags in the component

```
import React from 'react'

const Hello = (props) => (
    <div><h1>Hello, {props.name}!</h1></div>
)

export default Hello
```

I know I am missing something, but I am finding it hard to find info on doing this and would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Per the suggestion below, I tried to create a simple component and then hydrate it but I still get the same response.

Here is the new component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Hello extends React.Component {
    public load() {
        const xhr = require("xhr");
        let res = null;
        xhr({
            method: "get",
            sync: true,
            uri: "http://localhost:3000"
        }, (err, resp, body) => {
            res = body;
        });
        return res;
    }
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const val = this.load()
        return val;
    }
}

const target: any = document.querySelector("#main");
if (target) {
    ReactDOM.hydrate(<Hello />, target);
}
```

I am rather stumped right now.  Could it have to do with the response header type from the xhr request?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

JSX !== HTML they may appear the same but they are fundamentally different and cannot be used interchangeably.

`<div/>` in JSX is React.createElement("div");

`<div></div>` in HTML is document.createElement("div");

You cannot use HTML (or a HTML string) in place of a function in React that expects JSX (mainly ReactDOM.hydrate, ReactDOM.render, React.createElement("div", null, NEED JSX HERE).

In order to render it not as a string you'll have to use the only API implementation that React provides to turn a HTML string into something resembling JSX which is...

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: YOUR STRING HERE}}`

try this..

```
ReactDOM.render(<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: YOURSTRINGHERE}}/>, document.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's expects an Element, not a string.

```
ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Take that HTML response and create a react component out of it. Then pass it in your `.hydrate` method.

Comment: If you are reffering to :

const newEle = React.createElement("div", null, body);
ReactDOM.hydrate(newEle, document.getElementById("test"));

still shows as text..

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have enough reputation to comment on your main question, but have you tried setting the response content-type in express as 'text/html'?

```
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server"

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const name = 'Marvelous Peter'
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html'); // add this line
    res.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>My Page</title></head><body>");
    res.write("<div id='content'>");
    res.write(renderToString(<Hello name={name} />));
    res.write("</div></body></html>");
    res.end();
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Usually browsers will only understand that they need to render the incoming data as html if this header is specified.